# Crystal report fields are not refreshed if any changes made after debugging

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2008

![enter image description here][1]I am using visual studio 2008.In this my crystal report is not getting refreshed after debugging of first time.For the first time I added 5 fields from the field explorer and I start debugging,fields are displayed in the crystal report.After that my requirement is that I need to add 2 more fields from field explorer.I added and Saved,Build succeeded.When I debug now it is showing the old 5 fields not with the newly added 2 fields.
Whether  without my knowledge any property is changed or what is happening,Help me to find the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out whether your program is still in running condition or it stops completely, when you added new fields.

Comment: After closing the debug window,then only i did necessary changes in crystal report.

Comment: is your 'stop debugging' button in debug menu is enable or disable, when you added new field?

Comment: Stop debugging button is disable

Comment: I added the image of crystal report